How to make a three column, dynamic height grid with css
I'm trying to make a view for my website for reviews. Some reviews are longer than others, so the div containers of these reviews are going to be taller than other div containers. I've attached a picture of what I'm looking for. 
I read somewhere this can be done in flexbox but for the life of me I can't find it online. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is called a Masonry layout, and it currently can't be done dynamically with Flexbox or Grid (although one day Grid will have an option for this). You can get the job done with the Masonry JavaScript library.

Another option would be to use CSS columns, but you wouldn't get an even bottom, and the comments would be in columns rather than rows. Here's a recent video by Powell showing how: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/NNLxPcEnZDY

@ralph.m Thanks! I chose the CSS option. Works good in Chrome and Firefox, good enough for me!
